# Obtaining Map<String, Element> rather than Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Tags: json, dart

We start with a class `Element` for a member of the periodic table.

```
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

class Element {
  String name;
  Element({this.name = ""});
  String toString() {
    return this.name.toString();
  }
}
```

We can then decode a JSON string

```
void f1() {
  var jsonStr = """{ "Na": { "name": "Sodium" }, "Ca": { "name": "Calcium" } }""";

  final json = JSON.jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  print(json.runtimeType);  // MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>

  final elements = json.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, Element(name: value['name'])));
  
  print(elements.runtimeType);  // _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>
}
```

but suppose we want to specify the type of the result:

```
Map<String, Element> f3() {
  var jsonStr = """{ "Na": { "name": "Sodium" }, "Ca": { "name": "Calcium" } }""";

  final json = JSON.jsonDecode(jsonStr);

  final elements = Map<String, Element>.fromIterable(json,
    key: (k, v) => k,
    value: (k, v) => Element.fromJson(name: v['name'])
  );

  return elements;
}
```

How can I get around the following error?

```
Error: The argument type 'String Function(dynamic, dynamic)' can't be assigned
to the parameter type 'String Function(dynamic)?'.
```

to ensure that the returned object is of type `Map<String, Element>`?

Comment: You don't need the fromIterable stuff I think - as `json` is already a map.  Why not stick with your `f1` and do something like:  `Map<String, Element> elements = json.map<String, Element>((String key, value) => MapEntry(key, Element(name: value['name'])));`.

Comment: That also works. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `Map<K, V>.fromIterable` is:

```
Map<K, V>.fromIterable(
    Iterable iterable,
    {K key(
        dynamic element
    )?,
    V value(
        dynamic element
    )?}
)
```

Note that `key:` and `value:` both take functions of only one argument. The idea for `key` is to take an element from your iterable, and make a `Key` out of it - in your case, a `String`. Then for the `value` callback, you take the same element and make a `Value` out of it - in your case, an `Element`.

Also, a map is not iterable, but Map.entries is, so you need to iterate through `json.entries`, instead of just `json`.

So something like the following should get the job done:

```
final elements = Map<String, Element>.fromIterable(json.entries,
  key: (entry) => entry.key,
  value: (entry) => Element(name: entry.value['name']),
);
```